# Waiting for asynchronous result

Tags: jquery, facebook, asynchronous

I'm sick of the following problem:

I query the Facebooks API for some permissions by using the facebook function `FB.api()`. I want to wait for the result of this before I go on to proceed some tests etc. My aim is to create a small helper class to call often used functions by this class:

```
var fbHelper = {

    hasPermission: function(permission) {

            var hasPermission = false;
            var requestedPermissions = false;
            var permissions = { };

            FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response){    

                permissions = response;
                requestedPermissions = true;
                return response;
            });

            if(permissions){
                // make some checking stuff here
                return hasPermission;
            } else {
                console.log('failed to /me/permissions');
                return false;
            }        
     }
}
```

So i want to use `fbHelper.hasPermission('dummy')`. Unfortunately the `if(permissions)` is worked before `FB.Api()` is completed.
How can I achieve to wait for the rest of my code until the Api-Call is completed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really write a function that executes an asynchronous request and expect to be able to reliably return the result. I would restructure your helper method as follows:

```
hasPermission: function(permission, callback) {

        var hasPermission = false;
        var requestedPermissions = false;
        var permissions = { };

        FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response){    

            permissions = response;
            requestedPermissions = true;
            if (permissions) {
                callback(permissions);
            } else {
                callback(false);
            }
        });     
 }
```

Let calling code supply a callback function to be executed when the AJAX call has completed.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I've done it like your suggestion. The function now can handle 3 parameters (scope, callback_success, callback_error)

Answer (score 1):

You should move the code into your callback and return from there:

```
return FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response){    
    // this is your callback
    permissions = response;
    requestedPermissions = true;
    if(permissions){
        // make some checking stuff here
        return hasPermission;
    } else {
        console.log('failed to /me/permissions');
        return false;
    }      
});
```

Comment: the problem is that the inner return is not set as the FB.api return-value. FB.api() will return nothing whether the second parameter (function()) will return something or not.
I've solved the problem by passing a callback function to the hasPermission()-function call to call when the code in FB.api() was processed and the permission is granted

Answer (score 0):

If its asynchronous you need to have a callback, just like you have `function(response){}`. The fact that the javascript doesn't wait for the call to end is the entire purpose of asynchronous calls.