# What are the performance implications of waiting for callbacks to finish?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have been programming with Node.js for a little while, and I have found myself becoming increasingly annoyed with the need to chain callbacks. For example, when you need multiple models from a database as shown:

```
Person.findOne({ 'name.last': 'Ghost' }, 'name occupation', function (err, person) {
    Schedule.findOne({'person_id': person.id }, 'events', function(err, schedule) {
        ...
    }
})
```

I am looking for solutions to this problem. One idea I had was to do something like this:

```
function() {
    var p;
    var s;
    var done = false;

    Person.findOne(..., ..., function(err, person) {
        p = person;
        done = true;
    });

    while(!done){}
    done = false;

    Schedule.findOne(..., ..., function(err, schedule) {
        s = schedule;
        done = true;
    });

    while(!done){}
    done = false;

    // ...
}
```

If I do my queries like this, what are the performance implications? I'm also open to other ideas for solving this problem.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your most direct question, the performance implication of spin-waiting for a callback is that the spin-wait may starve other, more useful tasks from being completed, either in the same process or on the same machine.  If your application were running on a single-user machine with no power management, this wouldn't matter, but neither of those things is likely.  Busy-waiting will destroy battery life on mobile platforms, increase electricity costs in the datacenter, and make future maintainers of the code curse your name!

As elclanrs already suggested in a comment, you could look at the "[async](https://github.com/caolan/async)" library to help streamline your code, but in any case you should avoid busy waiting.

Comment: Does that mean that you can never return a value from a function that relied on a callback being completed? For instance, consider this:

`function test() { var p; Person.findOne(..., ..., function(err, person) { p = person; }); return p; }`

There is no guarantee that `test()` will not return `undefined`, correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's about the size of it.  Instead of returning a result, make the function take a callback which will be invoked when the result is ready.  This is discussed in more detail in other SO questions, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592385/waiting-for-asynchronous-result

Comment: Hmm interesting. I remember reading somewhere that you can do `thread.processNextEvent(true)` in order to do a non-busy wait (apparently there are also some dangerous side-effects).. Is there an equivalent to this in Node?

Comment: The operating principle of Node is asynchrony.  I suggest you stop trying to figure out ways to wait for an async event to complete, because you're just fighting against the way Node is meant to work.

Comment: Even the Node.JS way is asynchrony, eventually sometime you will need a sequencial way of routines to be done, this time you can't avoid the use of callback functions to accomplish this task.